# Hudson SonarPlugin fails if MAVEN_OPTS are set in build job

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, hudson, hudson-plugins

I configured a post build sonarqube analysis with the hudson SonarPlugin. I configured the MAVEN_OPTS for the SonarPlugin to be like this: 
"-Xmx1024m -Dmaven.javadoc.failOnError=false"

If I run the job there is an error when hudson tries to execute the post build action:

> [workspace] $ mvn -f /home/hudson-3.3.0/jobs/myJob/workspace/pom.xml -e -B sonar:sonar -Dsonar.jdbc.driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver -Dsonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxxx:1521/xxxx ******** ******** -Dsonar.host.url=http://xxxx:9000/sonar
>   Error: **Could not find or load main class MAVEN_OPTS**
>   Sonar analysis completed: FAILURE

I use the following setup:
Tomcat 8.0.24
Hudson 3.3.0
Sonar-Plugin 2.0.1
Maven 3.0.5 / 3.2.5
JDK 1.7.0_45

On a older hudson version with Sonar-Plugin 1.8.1 the build worked.

As workaround I configured my MAVEN_OPTS path variable to contain the expected settings but since I have to configure different jobs with different settings this is only a workaround.

Anybody got an idea how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can read in [Bug 474406](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=474406) it is a bug of Hudson 3.3.x. It has nothing to do with [Sonar Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Sonar+plugin) 2.0.1, which worked fine with Hudson 3.1.2.

It happens with Hudson post build action in:

- [Free-style project](http://www.eclipse.org/hudson/the-hudson-book/book-hudson.chunked/ch06.html#section-configuring-free-style-project)
- [Legacy Maven project type](http://www.eclipse.org/hudson/the-hudson-book/book-hudson.chunked/ch06.html#section-creating-new-project)

A work-around is to add a [build parameter](http://www.eclipse.org/hudson/the-hudson-book/book-hudson.chunked/ch06.html#section-common-job-configurations) to a job, see [Bug 474406](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=474406):

[image: Build parameter configuration]

Answer (score 1):

While dur's solution works fine, it has the downside of having the "build now" link asking for the build parameter instead of just building.

To get it working without the need for an parametrized build, I changed hudson's `$HOME/.mavenrc` to contain the following line:

```sh
export MAVEN_OPTS="$(echo ${MAVEN_OPTS} | sed -e 's#^MAVEN_OPTS ##')"
```

This strips the leading "MAVEN_OPTS" from the `MAVEN_OPTS` variable. So if hudson/the plugin is setting `MAVEN_OPTS="MAVEN_OPTS -Xmx128m"` this mavenrc will change MAVEN_OPTS to contain just `-Xmx128m`.